# In Javascript, under what conditions is it appropriate to only use `this` in constructor functions?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I found [an interesting line of code](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc#L61) in JSHint's config options.

The comment associated with the option reads `Tolerate using this in a non-constructor function.`

I am confused. Am I misunderstanding the config option?

Aren't there a lot of cases where you want to use `this` in a non-constructor function? When would you *ever* want to be warned about it?

Comment: Check this out:- http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This options is used to tell JSHint that a function will be invoked with a valid `this` parameter.

For example:

```
function myRandomFunction() {
    alert(this.something);
}

myRandomFunction.call(someObject);
```

If strict mode is on, JSHint will warn that `myRandomFunction` shouldn't be using `this`, since it doesn't look like a constructor or a member function.
If you know that it will always be called with a `this` (eg, as a callback), you can add `/*jshint validthis: true */` to suppress the warning.

Comment: This makes good sense. I guess the config option just needed a little bit more context :)

Answer (score -1):

I think that every "this" on a non-constructor function could be replaced with a meaningful parameter. On the other hand, badly implemented functions that use the "this" referenced object can easily mess up the application with hard-to-debug errors. So, I really think it's a valid option, specially if project team is large and some members aren't very experienced.

Comment: The statements `duck.quack()` and `quack(duck)` are completely different.

Comment: Fair enough.. While writing my answer I was thinking about functions, that aren't class members, messing up with the current scope..